# XML nodes editing.

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I assign values from a queryString to these textboxes and that works fine , but whenever I edit the text in one of them and try to get the edited data to be saved in XML node, I can't

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (Request.QueryString != null) 
    { 
        TextBox_firstname.Text = Request.QueryString["column1"]; 
        TextBox_lastname.Text = Request.QueryString["column2"]; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
    } 
}
```

Is there something with this code? It saves the unedited version in the nodes!

```
public string str_id; 
public int id; 
id = int.Parse(str_id); 

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filepath); 

if (id == 1) 
{ 
    var StudentNodeWithID1 = xdoc.Descendants("students") 
        .Elements("student") 
        .Where(s => s.Element("id").Value == "1") 
        .SingleOrDefault(); 
    StudentNodeWithID1.Element("first_name").Value = TextBox_firstname.Text; 
    StudentNodeWithID1.Element("last_name").Value = TextBox_lastname.Text; 
}
```

Comment: By "edit the text", do you mean type new text in a box(es) and submit the form (postback)? If so, your logic for testing the query string will still fire because the query string is (presumably) still present. If that's the case, you could check `IsPostback`. If that's not the case, post the event handler(s) from which the XML is being updated.

Answer (score 1):

Page_Load is fired on every load (on postback as well as on initial load). Your code is currently defaulting those values from `Request.QueryString` on every load, before your event handler tries to save it.

Do this instead:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            if (!IsPostBack && Request.QueryString != null) 
            { 
                TextBox_firstname.Text = Request.QueryString["column1"]; 
                TextBox_lastname.Text = Request.QueryString["column2"]; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting the edited textboxes, then you will need to wrap the code in your `Pageload` with `IsPostback` check to ensure that values do not get reset to their originals.